# XmlDoucment how to get bottom xmlnodes?

Tags: xmldocument

In xml document, I want to get the Bottom xml node, how can I get the last xml nodes

```
<Books>
  <book>
    <author> sasi </author>
    <pdate>2013-01-02</pdate>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author> surya</author>
    <pdate> 2013-02-02</pdate>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author>dolly</author>
    <pdate> 2013-04-01</pdate>
  </book>
</Books>
```

from the above I want get the last `<book>` node in the xml document.

Comment: Your XML is not valid.

Comment: what's your programming language ? !!!

Comment: C# is my programminglanguage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xml = @"<Books>
                <book>
                  <author> sasi </author>
                  <pdate>2013-01-02</pdate>
                </book>
                <book>
                  <author> surya</author>
                  <pdate> 2013-02-02</pdate>
                </book>
                <book>
                  <author>dolly</author>
                  <pdate> 2013-04-01</pdate>
                </book>
            </Books>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var node = doc.FirstChild.LastChild;
Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
```

Outputs:

```
<book><author>dolly</author><pdate> 2013-04-01</pdate></book>
```

Alternatively, you may select the last `book` child under the `Books` element:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("Books/book[last()]")
```

or the last `book` element no matter where they are in the document:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("//book[last()]");
```

Comment: i tried var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
 XmlNode xmlns = XD.FirstChild.LastChild; from here i am not able to get the  author node inner text

Comment: Use `node1.SelectSingleNode("author").InnerText`.